# MongoDB: SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

So I have a basic test db with Mongo setup. Here is what the `users` collection currently looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8e23ed2f8849a57711e48e"),
    "firstName" : "Joe",
    "lastName" : "Black",
    "email" : "joeblack@gmail.com",
    "portfolio" : [ ],
    "watchlist" : [ ],
    "goals" : [ ],
    "badges" : [ ],
    "ranks" : [ ],
    "hasPortfolio" : false,
    "hasWatchlist" : false,
    "hasGoals" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8e23ed2f8849a57711e48f"),
    "firstName" : "Juan",
    "lastName" : "Gonzales",
    "email" : "juangonzales@outlook.com",
    "portfolio" : [ ],
    "watchlist" : [ ],
    "goals" : [ ],
    "badges" : [ ],
    "ranks" : [ ],
    "hasPortfolio" : false,
    "hasWatchlist" : false,
    "hasGoals" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8e338fe0562db42af793c9"),
    "firstName" : "Foo",
    "lastName" : "Bar",
    "email" : "foobar@baz.com",
    "portfolio" : [ ],
    "watchlist" : [ ],
    "goals" : [ ],
    "ranks" : [ ],
    "badges" : [
        {
            "name" : "Tester",
            "type" : "bronze",
            "new" : true
        }
    ],
    "hasPortfolio" : false,
    "hasWatchlist" : false,
    "hasGoals" : false
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is update the `portfolio` array on user `foobar@baz.com`. But I keep getting the following error:

> 2019-09-27T13:07:00.590-0500 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):6:8

### The command

```
db.users.update({email: 'foobar@baz.com'}, {
  $set: {
    portfolio: [
      {
        availableSupply: "1000000"
        currency: "SHIT"
        exchange: "Binance",
        exchange_base: "btc",
        marketCap: 10000,
        name: "ShitCoin",
        percentage: 100,
        price: 0.01,
        position: 1,
        value: 0.01,
        inWatchlist: false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: You missed a comma after `availableSupply: "1000000"` and `currency: "SHIT"`

Comment: It looks to me as though you're missing a comma after `currency: "SHIT"`

Comment: suggest to delete the question as it just was couple of typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plz try this

```
db.users.update({email: 'foobar@baz.com'}, {
  $set: {
    portfolio: [
      {
        availableSupply: "1000000",
        currency: "SHIT",
        exchange: "Binance",
        exchange_base: "btc",
        marketCap: 10000,
        name: "ShitCoin",
        percentage: 100,
        price: 0.01,
        position: 1,
        value: 0.01,
        inWatchlist: false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the commas after each item:

```
portfolio: [
  {
    availableSupply: "1000000", // You missed these
    currency: "SHIT", // You missed these
    exchange: "Binance",
    exchange_base: "btc",
    marketCap: 10000,
    name: "ShitCoin",
    percentage: 100,
    price: 0.01,
    position: 1,
    value: 0.01,
    inWatchlist: false
  }
]
```